# It is Possible to connect the site page with layout pages SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2007

It is possible to connect the site pages with layout page in SharePoint 2010. I did, but i have a problem when i am saving the data (i.e. publish the page) it gives me the following error:

> Error  An unexpected error has
>   occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID:
>   9bc41e28-4fe1-4b4f-9e00-0e0494ef9e6e
>
> Date and Time: 7/1/2010 3:30:29 AM

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by looking up the correlation id in your ULS log (c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs)

Answer (score 0):

No, You cannot connect site page with an application page. However you can pass the URL of your custom application under layouts on site pages. Because site page is an OOTB feature available in SharePoint whereas layouts pages are Application pages. Application page can be custom developed and deployed under layouts. These pages can have custom logic and custom view but site page cannot have your custom logic and view.

You can use Web parts in site pages to achieve something which needs customization, or can user OOTB web parts available in SharePoint for displaying the data from the list.